# Marketing Cloud: "Textarea" field type on Cloud Page not updating Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

We designed a cloudpage with a simple form (bootstrap CSS utilized) that has just 2 'textarea' types of fields (so, basically, free comment areas). Although the form validates without any errors, the updates are not being passed into Data Extension. We are using SAP_Account as PrimaryKey.

Here's the code we used - AMPscript and some html (I'm not pasting the entire html, no need):

Page 1:

```
AMPscript
    %%[ /* Page 1 */
    VAR @externalID, @url
    SET @externalID=RequestParameter('CustomerID')
    SET @url=CloudPagesURL(1691,'CustomerID', @externalID)
    ]%%
<!-- HTML - form part - page 1 -->
<div class="optin-form">
             <form action="%%=CloudPagesURL(1691)=%%" method="GET">
               <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textArea1">Question 1?
</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="textArea1" id="textArea1" rows="8"></textarea>
  </div>
               <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textArea2">Question 2? 
</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="textArea2" id="textArea2" rows="8"></textarea>
  </div>
                <div class="btn-wrapper">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="CustomerID" value="%%=v(@externalID)=%%">
              </form>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
    %%[
    /*Page 2 AMPscript - validation */

    %%[

    VAR @externalID, @extID, @url, @textArea1, @textArea2

    SET @externalID=RequestParameter('CustomerID')


    SET @textArea1 = RequestParameter('textArea1')
    SET @textArea2 = RequestParameter('textArea2')

    IF NOT EMPTY(@textArea1) THEN
    UpsertDE('Key_Priorities', 1, 'CustomerID', @externalID, 'Employee_life', @textArea1)
    ENDIF

    IF NOT EMPTY(@textArea2) THEN
    UpsertDE('Key_Priorities', 1, 'CustomerID', @externalID, 'Customer_life', @textArea2)
    ENDIF

    SET @url=CloudPagesURL(1690, 'CustomerID', @externalID)

    ]%%
<!-- html page 2- form continue-->
<div class="background-gradiant">
  <form action="%%=CloudPagesURL(1690)=%%" method="post">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 background-white">

            <div class="title-h3" style="color: #000000;">Thank You!</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you need to name the textareas as the RequestParameter in your processing page looks via name/value pairing in POST data header. e.g. `name="textarea1"`

Comment: Yes, exactly, that was the problem! After I added name/value into html the form started working properly. Thank you!

Comment: Added as an answer for easy reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to name the textareas as the RequestParameter in your processing page looks via name/value pairing in POST data header.

For example:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textArea2">Question 2?</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="textArea2" id="textArea2" rows="8"></textarea>
  </div>
```